# Printing a list after having removed adjacent duplicate elements

Tags: python, recursion

```
new_list = []

i = 0

def remove_adjacent(nums):
    global i
    while i < len(nums) - 1:
        if nums[i] != nums[i+1]:
            new_list.append(nums[i])
        else:
            i += 1
            remove_adjacent(nums[i:])
            return
    i += 1

l = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8]

remove_adjacent(l)

print new_list
```

Question: Given a list of numbers, return a list where all adjacent == elements have been reduced to a single element, so `[1, 2, 2, 3]` returns `[1, 2, 3]`. You may create a new list or modify the passed in list.

Issue: The final list printed consists of `[1, 2, 3, 5]` instead of `[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8]`

Comment: In the loop, print some of your *variables* to see what is happening. One easy way to get pairs of adjacent items in a list is `for a, b, in zip(nums, nums[1:]: print(a,b)` - don't know if that will help.

Comment: I'm not doing your assignment for you, of course, but it looks like you were trying to decide whether to use a loop OR recursion, but you ended up doing both at the same time. (PS: get rid of the globals. Use the return.)

Comment: @KennyOstrom I never asked anyone to do my assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_list = []

def remove_adjacent(nums):
    i = 0
    while i < len(nums) - 1:
        if nums[i] != nums[i+1]:
            new_list.append(nums[i])
        else:
            i += 1
            remove_adjacent(nums[i:])
            return
        i += 1

l = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8]

remove_adjacent(l)

# appending the last item
new_list.append(l[len(l)-1])

print (new_list.append(nums[len(nums) - 1]))
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8]
```

Comment: i = 0 inside remove_adjacent worked like a charm and I was thinking writing i = 0 would re-initialize i to zero but what I didn't realize that that would be local to that recursive call!!

Comment: @being_resilient thanks! please note that I appended the last item. check if that can be avoided.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway I was going to figure out that myself for that I was running the loop one less time.

Answer (score 3):

What you would want is a problem best solved by [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
l
Out[35]: [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8]

from itertools import groupby
[k for k, _ in groupby(l)]
Out[36]: [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8]
```

What `itertools.groupby` does is, it groups consecutive keys together by generating a tuple of the element and the consecutive group as a list

To get a clear understanding of `itertools.groupby`, you can dump the resultant list of tuples generated by grouping the list of consecutive numbers

```
[(k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(l)]
Out[40]: 
[(1, [1]),
 (2, [2]),
 (3, [3]),
 (5, [5]),
 (4, [4, 4]),
 (5, [5, 5]),
 (6, [6]),
 (7, [7, 7, 7]),
 (8, [8, 8]),
 (9, [9]),
 (8, [8, 8])]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perfect for a generator.  I'm not altering the original list.  Instead, I'm returning a new list with no adjacent values equal to one another.

```
def removerator(l):
    last = None
    for x in l:
        if x != last:
            last = x
            yield x

list(removerator(l))

[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8]
```

---

**Setup**

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8]
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a function where it get a list and iterate over its items, then it adds the items that aren't the same as the items already added to the list in the previous iteration.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8]  # List that we want to change

def remove_adjacent(l):             # Define a new function and accept an argument: the list to check.
    new = [l[0]]                    # Make a new list (temporal) and assing like it's first item the first item of the main list. It's the same as new = [] and new.append(l[0]).
    for item in l[1:]:              # We iterate across the list, but we don't iterate on the first item because we've alreaday added it to the list, if you want you can delete the slice in [1:] since it will only make the iteration a really small fraction more slowly.
        if new[-1] != item:         # We check if the new item is the same as the last item added to the new list, if not, we add it.
            new.append(item)        # We add the item to the new list.
    return new                      # We return the list.

print(remove_adjacent(l))           # We check it.
# [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8]
```